# How to select clustered markers in leaflet with crosstalk

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to to combine a `leaflet` map with `crosstalk` so users can select points on the map and the data associated with these points will be displayed in a `DT` data table.

In this modified example from [the Crosstalk webpage](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/), users can successfully select points on the map and have the corresponding data shown in the table.

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

sd <- SharedData$new(quakes)

bscols(
  leaflet(sd) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(),
  datatable(sd)
)
```

But when I use clustered markers, as in the code below, I'm no longer able to select and sort.

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

sd <- SharedData$new(quakes)

bscols(
  leaflet(sd) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()),
  datatable(sd)
)
```

Is there a way to regain this functionality?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround, especially for smaller datasets, is to plot the individual markers as circles with the stroke and fill opacity set to 0, as shown below.

```r
library(crosstalk) # not on CRAN, devtools::install_github("rstudio/crosstalk")
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

sd <- SharedData$new(quakes)

bscols(
  leaflet(sd) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(fillOpacity = 0, opacity = 0) %>% 
    addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()),
  datatable(sd)
)
```